# eslint error for using a specific function

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

I have a function in my react application which I want to move away from. I want to show eslint error when a developer calls/uses that function. Is there a way for that.

For now I have used `@deprecated` comment on top with some info on why not to use it. It strikes through anywhere where the function is called.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-deprecation, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you're doing the exact right thing: `@deprecated` is the right JSDoc/TSDoc tag for this. [`eslint-plugin-deprecation`](https://github.com/gund/eslint-plugin-deprecation) is an ESLint plugin that can be configured to give errors or warnings on uses of things marked as `@deprecated`.